# How to create functional Methods

Tags: javascript, function, methods

What I want to approach is to create a custom Function that looks like this:

```
access('h1').content('Hello World');
```

And this is how I tried to accomplish that:

```
function access(Tag)
{
  var Element = document.getElementsByTagName(Tag)[0];

  this.content = function(Content)
  {
     if (Content !== undefined)
          return Element.innerHTML = Content;
     else return Element.innerHTML;
  }

  return Element;
}
```

So this Function shall be in the verge of changing the Content or just returning it.
Unfortunately it does not work this Way.

So far I played with it for about an Hour to rewrite it and find a Solution on my own, but I have not been successfull and I also do not know how to describe this Problem to Google it.

How can I solve this it?

Comment: just return `this` or the element performing operation on, at the end.

Comment: There is problem in logical operator, !== should be !=

Comment: Daniel, it looks like you come from C# or some other similar language, and JS is very different. You should read [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)!

Comment: This is definitely not called "functional methods"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `this` with `Element` in your code.

```js
function access(Tag)
    {
      var Element = document.getElementsByTagName(Tag)[0];
    
      Element.content = function(Content)
      {
         if (Content !== undefined)
              return Element.innerHTML = Content;
         else return Element.innerHTML;
      }
    
      return Element;
    }
    
access('h1').content('Hello World');
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

**Or** try something like this.

```js
function access(Tag)
    {
      var Element = document.getElementsByTagName(Tag)[0];
    
      var content = function(Content)
      {
         if (Content !== undefined)
              return Element.innerHTML = Content;
         else return Element.innerHTML;
      }
    
      return {content: content};
    }
    
access('h1').content('Hello World');
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you. The second Way worked for me